# The entity type "XXX" is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am inserting data in one table and want to update data of another table just like we do in winforms c#. I want that when some buy a product its quantity will be updated in another table. but I am receiving this error :
"The entity type Products is not part of the model for the current context."

My code is below :

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Purchase()
    {
        if (Session["userId"] != null)
        {
            int a = (int)Session["userId"];
            var maxId = //(from k in mse.Orders where k.user_Id == a select  k.Order_Id).Max(); 
                mse.Orders.Where(r => r.user_Id == a).OrderByDescending(r => r.Order_Id).First();
            ViewBag.oId = maxId.Order_Id;
            var reg = (from abc in mse.Registerations where abc.Register_Id == a select abc).First();
            ViewBag.shipAd = reg.shippingAddress;
            ViewBag.quantity = maxId.Quantity;
            TempData["quantity"] = ViewBag.quantity;
            var prodId = maxId.Product_Id;
            var pId = (from f in mse.Products where f.Product_Id == prodId select f).OrderByDescending(f => f.Product_Id).First();
            ViewBag.price = pId.unitPrice;

        }


        return View();
    }
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Purchase(Purchase p)
{
if (Session["userId"] != null)
{
p.Register_Id = (int)Session["userId"];
int a = Convert.ToInt16(TempData["productId"]);
int b = Convert.ToInt16(TempData["quantity"]);

var subQuanitty = (from s in mse.Products where s.Product_Id == a select s).First();
int quantity = Convert.ToInt16(subQuanitty.Quantity) - b;
Products prod = new Products();
prod.Quantity = b.ToString();

updateProduct(prod);

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
mse.Purchases.Add(p);
mse.SaveChanges();

return RedirectToAction("Status");
}
}

return View(p);
}

public void updateProduct(Products prod)
{
mse.Entry(prod).State = EntityState.Modified;
mse.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: In which line the error occurred? Are you sure `Products` table already included as data model class inside your data context?

Comment: Actually i am trying when data will inserted in purchase table then quantity of product table will be updated. I am facing error in this method  :                                                                                           public void updateProduct(Products prod)
{
mse.Entry(prod).State = EntityState.Modified;
mse.SaveChanges();
}

Comment: I suspected the error occurred when setting `mse.Entry(prod).State = EntityState.Modified;` and then saving modified items into DB. Try using `Attach` method to `prod` entity then perform data update.

Comment: Ok.Now i am trying attach method.